# Evaluate/calculate math equation with every entry in array

Tags: python, list, numpy-ndarray

I have an array and an equation.

I want to plug in all array values into the equation and save it.

What I've tried until now:

```
import math
import numpy as np

Z_F0=376.73
Epsilon=3.66

wl_range = [np.arange(0.1, 50, 0.1)]
wl_array = np.array(wl_range)
multiplied_array = 6+(2*math.pi*6)*math.exp(-1*(30.666/wl_array)**0.7528)
print(multiplied_array)
```

Or I've tried `multiplied_array = np.vectorize(6+(2*math.pi*6)...)`

But I get the

> ```
> only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
> ```

error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `math`, `numpy` has `pi` and `exp`. `pi` would have worked with `math`, as it is just a constant. But the content of your exponential is a vector, so you need to use `numpy` for that.

There are situations where `math` is faster (when you don't vectorize), as `numpy`  has higher overhead checking for the dimensions of your input.

```
import numpy as np

Z_F0=376.73
Epsilon=3.66

wl_range = [np.arange(0.1, 50, 0.1)]
wl_array = np.array(wl_range)
multiplied_array = 6+(2*np.pi*6)*np.exp(-1*(30.666/wl_array)**0.7528)
print(multiplied_array)
```

output:

```
[ 6.          6.          6.          6.          6.00000001  6.00000015
   6.00000127  6.00000656  6.00002459  6.00007283  6.00018111  6.00039369
   6.0007699   6.00138329  6.00231952  6.00367362  6.00554684  6.00804354
   6.01126831  6.01532348  6.020307    6.02631085  6.03341981  6.04171066
   6.0512517   6.06210249  6.07431393  6.08792837  6.10297998  6.11949516
   6.13749297  6.15698571  6.17797939  6.20047433  6.22446568  6.24994393
   6.27689541  6.30530278  6.33514546  6.36640006  6.39904075  6.43303963
   6.46836702  6.50499181  6.54288169  6.58200341  6.62232297  6.66380586
   6.70641722  6.75012196  6.79488494  6.84067111  6.88744554  6.93517359
   6.98382097  7.03335377  7.08373859  7.13494255  7.18693331  7.23967918
   7.29314908  7.34731259  7.40213999  7.45760222  7.51367097  7.5703186  ...
```

Answer (score 3):

`math.exp()` only works with a *scalar* argument `x`. If you use `numpy.exp()` then the equation should work.